# locust interface keeps at 0 rps

Tags: python, testing, load-testing, locust

I am trying to do a load test of one mysql server mounted in a container in a VM with ubuntu server. For this I wrote the following script in python:

```
...

# Cria bot de teste
class MyUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 5)

    @task(1)
    def get_price(self):
        try:
            # Estabelece conexão com o banco de dados MySQL
            with connect(
                host="192.168.0.9",
                user="root",
                password="123",
                database="test1",
                port=3306
            ) as connection:
                with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                    # Executa uma query que busca o preço do produto
                    cursor.execute("SELECT preco FROM estoque WHERE id_codigo_barras = %s", ("3756392598566",))
                    result = cursor.fetchone()
                    price = result[0]
                    # Imprime o preço do produto retornado pelo banco de dados
                    print("Preço do produto: {}".format(price))
        except Error as e:
            print(e)
```

when I use the following command, the interface begins to work:

`> locust -f advanced/tools/direct_locust_loadtest.py --host=http://localhost:8080`

in the interface i set as the image:

[config of test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeQB9.png)

but the 0 rps keeps at 0, even though the prompt is generating responses.

[prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/destf.png)

i alredy tried:

- test if is running correctly and requests are being logged to the IDE's prompt.
- opened browser and entered the address "http://localhost:8089".
- check if the user class name in the Python file is exactly "MyUser" and that the methods are correctly annotated with the "@task" decorator.
- checked if on the Locust browser page, selected the "Charts" tab and make sure the "Requests per second" option is selected.
- reload the page / restarting the Locust server several times.

I tried everything suggested by chatgpt and it even advised coming here to ask for help. Can anyone give a hint?

thank you very much!!!

Comment: I alredy used more clients too (100 with 10 spawn/s). Still 0 RPS.

Answer (score 0):

Locust only knows what you're doing when you tell it. There are [Event Hooks](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#events) that you use to tell Locust what's going on in your code. If you use Locust's `HttpUser` and then use `self.client` to make http calls, the proper events are normally fired for you automatically, making less work for you unless you want to override the default events.

In your case, even though you're using `HttpUser` you're not using `self.client` to make http calls so Locust is not firing events for you (as an aside, you can use just `User` instead) and you have to fire events yourself like:

```
self.environment.events.request.fire(
        request_type="MySQL",
        name="execute id_codigo_barras",
        response_time=(time.perf_counter() - start_perf_counter) * 1000,
        response_length=response_length,
        response=response,
        context=None,
        exception=exception,
    )
```

All of the parameters in the event are customizable. Put in whatever strings or other data that fits your need and Locust will report it as is. See [the Locust docs](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/testing-other-systems.html) for more examples.